# Open MPI can't launch remote nodes via SSH

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, mpi, hpc, openmpi

I am trying to set up Open MPI between a few machines on out network.
Open MPI works fine locally, but I just can't get it to work on a remote node.
I can ssh into the remote machine (without password) just fine, but if I try something like

```
mpiexec -n 4 --host remote.host hello_c
```

then the ssh connection just times out.

I checked several tutorials but the only configuration instructions they give is "make sure you can ssh into the remote machine without a password". I did and I still can't launch nodes on remote machines. What's the problem?

Comment: Check that Open MPI (or at least its runtime components) is installed on the remote machine and that it is available in the default `PATH`. You might need to supply the `--prefix /path/to/ompi/install`. Also run `mpiexec` in verbose mode with `-v` or enable ORTE debugging with `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same issue. Try to connect in ssh with rsa certificates

Edit 03/24 : This not work.. sorry